# 90s/80s animated movie involving a kid, a worm-like alien, and treasure

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens, animation

I am looking for an animated movie which is about a kid who finds a worm-like alien. Somewhere in the movie this worm-like alien gets captured by a guy in a suit and a woman. Where it finds other aliens. The man in the suit is looking for a treasure. They use the alien to find an old building in the forest with treasure in it. The treasure consists of gold coins and gemstones. While the man and woman are distracted the alien reunites with the other aliens and there is a strobe of lights. This turns the man and woman frozen in a metallic like appearance. The alien says goodbye to the kid.

I believe the main character was a white boy with brown hair and there might have been a girl as well. I would have seen it in the early 90s but not sure when the movie was made. The alien was striped green. It was a shorter fatter one. When it finds the other aliens they range from being long and skinny and short and fat worm like. All same shade of green with a horizontal stripes. The villains were white and the man had black hair and sunglasses with a blue suit. I believe the woman wore a dress.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you watch this? Also, was the kid a boy or a girl, and do you recall the colour of their hair?

Comment: And do you remember the skin color of any of the characters?

Comment: I believe the main character was a bit with brown hair and there might have been a girl as well. I would have seen it in the early 90s but not sure when the movie was made. The alien was striped green. It was a shorter fatter one. When it finds the other aliens they range from being long and skinny and short and fat worm like. All same shade of green with a horizontal stripes. The villain had black hair and sunglasses with a blue suit. I believe the woman wore a dress.

Comment: Welcome to SFF! Can you [edit] those details into the question?

Comment: Your title mentions treasure, can you please add in any details you remember about/relating to this treasure? With story ID questions generally any detail you remember, no matter how small, may be the thing that triggers someone's recollection.

Comment: The treasure is what the guy in the suit is after. He captures the alien and bring it and the boy to the forest , where they are able to find and old building with treasure in it.

Comment: @Jimbob You can use the 'edit' button at the bottom of your question to add this (and any other new information) to your question.

Comment: Also, if you remember what the treasure was (gold, coins, alien artefacts?) you can add that in too.

Comment: As posted by Machavity, there's also the [edit] link generated using square brackets in a comment. :)

Comment: Were the humans light-skinned? Dark-skinned? Visibly of a particular ethnic group?